# Sidebar and Content don't adjust width properly

Tags: css, layout, width, margin

I'm currently running in circles with my actually very basic CSS.
I am writing a front-end for a mail client and got a main (body) container containing the sidebar and the "innerContainer", that should fill out the space that's left after the sidebar.

Important HTML:

```
    <div id="outerContainer">
        <div id="sideBar">
        </div>
        <div id="innerContainer">
            <!-- not important ;D -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Important CSS:

```
#sideBar {
    margin: 4px 2px 4px 4px;
    height: 644px;
    width: 14%;
    min-width: 220px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
}

#innerContainer {
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 2px;
    height: 644px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: right;
}
```

I am currently trying to let the client determine the perfect width by not using any width-property in the rules for #innerContainer. Using that, it's just 0px, even though the margin should leave a 4px space between both elements.
Using a fixed width (or percents) makes it look horrible when changing screen resolution to anything widescreen.

I would appreciate any tips, feel free to request more code, screenshots or something like that.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9bwN/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sideBar {
  float:left;
}
#innerContainer {
  display:table-cell;
  zoom:1;/*for IE*/
}
```

check this -  http://jsfiddle.net/fRBWe/11/

Comment: Using this the innerContainer is 1px wide, that doesn't really fit my needs. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's almost it! Thanks a lot :D But now it seems to ignore the margin and leaves 0px space between the sideBar and innerContainer instead of the supposed 4px, also it's ignoring the other margins, too.

Comment: Because of its a table cell css margin won't get applied on it. use border or padding. I don't know about your need. Hope it will help

Comment: Using padding it works, but it feels like hacking. As far as I know formatting using tables is deprecated since long ago. Although currently there seems to be no other possibility. ^^"

Comment: Okay. Tables can be sill use for good reason. Since you can't accept it with whole heart.. check this solution - now with position http://jsfiddle.net/fRBWe/24/

Comment: Absolute positioning isn't possible with these two elements, as they should be both resizeable for multiple screen resolutions. I updated the Question with a fiddle of the exact code.

Comment: Yes absolute position will work. But the problem is with the min-width. You have to take care min-width situation through javasript.
http://jsfiddle.net/L9bwN/4/

Comment: Thanks for this! I guess that's the best solution I can get for this :)
Also thanks for all your time. ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Changed a bit of your css.. here's the new css

```
body , html{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}

#sideBar {
margin: 0px 2px 4px 4px;
height: 644px;
width: 14%;
min-width: 220px;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: black;
float: left;
}

#innerContainer {
margin: 4px 4px 4px 2px;
height: 644px;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: pink;
}​
```

You can check the demo here

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8yTaz/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) The innerContainer should be on the right of the sideBar, so that's not exactly what I am searching, sorry.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong - in my experience ( which is short,i know!! ) , without using width's property - it isnt possible..

Answer (score 0):

What if you split up major layout from the spacing?

So..

```
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="sideBar-wrap">
        <div id="sideBar">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="innerContainer-wrap">
        <div id="innerContainer">
            <!-- not important ;D -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then

```
#sideBar-wrap {
    height: 644px;
    width: 14%;
    min-width: 220px;
    float: left;
}
#sideBar {
    margin: 4px 2px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
#innerContainer-wrap {
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 2px;
    height: 644px;
    float: right;
}
#innerContainer {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ^-^ Using this the innerContainer-wrap is wide enough, even overlapping the sidebar. But the innerContainer is still just 0px wide.